# Paranoia Gem - joins with deleted items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-paranoia

I'm using Paranoia gem and now struggling with the problem. I need to joins  `has_many` deleted items, but it returns not deleted only. My models:

```
class Mailing < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_paranoid

  has_many :mailing_fields
  has_many :fields, through: :mailing_fields

end

class MailingField < ActiveRecord::

  belongs_to :mailing
  belongs_to :field

end

class Field < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :mailing_fields, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :mailings, through: :mailing_fields

end
```

Query I'm running which should return `mailings` with deleted items:

```
Field.joins(:mailings).where('mailings.id = ?', mailing_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paranoid` gem sets a default scope of only including non-deleted items in queries. The workaround would be:

```
Field.joins(:mailings).where('mailings.id = ? AND mailings.deleted_at IS NOT NULL', mailing_id)
```

Answer (score 7):

The only working solution I've found so far is to manually specify the JOIN:

```
Field.joins('INNER JOIN "mailings" ON "mailings"."id" = "fields"."mailing_id"')
     .where('mailings.id = ?', mailing_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

`unscoped` also accepts a block, so you you can do the following:

```
Mailing.unscoped do
  Field.joins(:mailings).where('mailings.id = ?', mailing_id)
end
```

See: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-unscoped

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the scope in your query as such:

```
Field.joins(:mailings).where("mailings.deleted_at != :deleted_status OR mailings.deleted_at = :deleted_status", deleted_status: nil).where(mailings: { id: mailing_id })
```

OR since you're trying to fetch the `Field` which seems to be a many to many relationship, I'd prefer to invert the query as such:

```
Mailing.unscoped.joins(:fields).find(mailing_id).fields
```

Let me know if i was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit too late to the party, but this can help if someone stumbles upon this problem.

You can create an additional association between parent and child to include the deleted records as well.

In context of the question asked,

```
class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mailing_fields, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :mailing_fields_with_deleted, -> { with_deleted }
 
  has_many :mailings, through: :mailing_fields
  has_many :mailings_with_deleted, through: :mailing_fields_with_deleted
end
```

and then use this relation:
`Field.joins(:mailings_with_deleted).where('mailings.id = ?', mailing_id)`

Comment: I always thought this was true but I traced a bug in our code down to this scenario(mine is from a belongs_to) and found that `Field.joins(:mailings_with_deleted)` is producing sql like `SELECT * FROM fields INNER JOIN mailings.field_id ON field.id AND mailings.delete_at is NULL`. What is odd however is that if I do field.mailing_fields_with_deleted then its including the deleted items. Seems like a bug between paranoia / ActiveRecord some how to me

Comment: There is a related open github issue here with further discussion https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia/issues/330

Answer (score -1):

Paranoid gem has built-in scope to access deleted items: with_deleted.

```
Mailing.with_deleted.joins(:fields).where(id: mailing_id)
```

Comment: This is insufficient if the parent `MailingField` object to the `Field` object is also deleted. Even with `with_deleted`, it will still apply the `mailing_fields.deleted_at IS NULL` conditional to the join. Try it out for yourself by add `.to_sql` on the end of this. You'll see it still there.